# Showing Directory Root When Launching Rails App Using Apache2 and Passenger

Tags: apache2, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

I have done the following in an attempt to host a Rails 3.2.3 application using Apache 2.2.21 and Passenger 3.0.13:

1. Installed gem Passenger
2. rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module
3. Added website info in /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
4. Added line to /etc/hosts (not sure if this was needed or not; not mentioned in Passenger documentation
5. Uncommented out the line in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to Include /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
6. Restarted Apache

When I try to pull up my website the following displays:

```
Index of /

    Name    Last modified   Size    Description

Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.10 with Suhosin-Patch Phusion_Passenger/3.0.13 Server at lightbesandbox2.com Port 443
```

Here is /etc/hosts entry for the website:

```
127.0.0.1   www.lightbesandbox2.com
```

Here is my /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf entry for the website:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.lightbesandbox2.com
  ServerAlias lightbesandbox2.com
  PassengerAppRoot /Users/server1/Sites/iktusnetlive_RoR/ 
  DocumentRoot /Users/server1/Sites/iktusnetlive_RoR/public    
  <Directory /Users/server1/Sites/iktusnetlive_RoR/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I do rvmsudo passenger-status I get the following output:

```
----------- General information -----------
max      = 6
count    = 1
active   = 0
inactive = 1
Waiting on global queue: 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/Users/server1/Sites/iktusnetlive_RoR/:
  App root: /Users/server1/Sites/iktusnetlive_RoR/
  * PID: 8140    Sessions: 0    Processed: 2       Uptime: 20m 51s
```

None of my assets are in the public folder in my Rails app.  I have written an application using the template presented in Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial.  The home page is in /app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb.  I decided to copy an index.html file in the public folder to see if it would display.  It displayed as I had hoped..

Is there a way to get Passenger to find my assets without me having to rewrite my application?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this might help
http://www.ajibanda.com/2010/12/install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-server.html

though, it is usinhg 2.1, you can use this as a guide on setting up the passenger starting from step 7